# postgres 11.4 fails to start when wal_level is set to minimal

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7

I have migrated my data by dumping and reloading it from pg9.3 to pg11.4 which went fine. And I am able to run the new server with default config

The pg11.4 works fine but it fails to restart when I set in `postgres.conf` to

```
wal_level = minimal
```

This same setting works in my 9.3 instance but not in 11.4

Is there any config setting that could conflict with `wal_level = minimal` ?

Answer (score 5):

It is no problem to start PostgreSQL v11 with `wal_level=minimal` unless there is another configuration setting that conflicts with it. For example, `archive_mode` cannot be `on`, and `max_wal_senders` has to be 0.

Look into the PostgreSQL log file for the error message, or start PostgreSQL manually with

```bash
pg_ctl start -D datadir
```

to see the message that will tell you the exact reason why the server failed to start.

Comment: On pg 14 my server, 'wal_level=minimal' fails to start with 'background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 37336) exited with exit code 1'.
Should I prevent this background worker from starting at all, e.g. max_wall_senders=0?
That appears a bit rude, so advice is much appreciated!

Comment: @Jan You will have to set `max_wal_senders` to 0, and there is nothing rude about that. It is mentioned in the documentation of `wal_level`.